# How to get path withTkinter filedialog?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to get the selected path within a Filedialog tkinter but I do not know how to because when choosing the path directly in the graphical window save as there is no way to extract the path to store it in a variable

```
from tkinter import filedialog
open_f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
path_f =
```

As you can see I need to store the route obtained in open_f within the variable path_f .. but open_f only returns a _io.textiowrapper..

How do you get the path in a filedialog?

Comment: There's `filedialog.asksaveasfilename(...)` if all you need is the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is actually a filename, use `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
print(filepath)
# '/home/norok2/.xsession-errors'
```

Comment: This works but it opens a TK window with nothing inside. Is there any way to disable the tk window ? Also the type file list is empty although is add `defaultextension='.pdf'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `name` method of your object. Like below:

```
open_f = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
path_f = your_file.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def open():
    open_f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    path_f = open_f.name
    # You Can Do Anything Here(e.g. print(path_f))
```

Full code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def open():
    open_f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    path_f = open_f.name
    print(path_f)
# '/home/norok2/.xsession-errors'

# You can run it by typing:
open()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".xlsx")
out.close()

restr = str(out)
    
RegexPrep = restr.replace("'w'", '')
outRegex = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", RegexPrep)
ToExcelRegex = str(outRegex)
    
MorePrep = ToExcelRegex.replace("[",'')
MorePrep = MorePrep.replace("]",'')
MorePrep = MorePrep.replace("'",'')
MorePrep = MorePrep.replace(", cp1252",'')
Final = MorePrep.strip()
```

A simpler way to do it:

```
open_f = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
path_f = your_file.name
```